# php - how to keep whatever is shuffled

Tags: php

I'm making a quiz, and the answer at the end is shuffled, but what I don't want is that when ever page is refreshed the value changes because it's being shuffled. Anyways is there a way not to keep it from being shuffled over and over?

For example, when I get the answer "2" and the page is refreshed... I want it to stay at answer "2" ... if possible please help, thank you!

echo works fine, its just that i don't want it to keep shuffling when page is refreshed.

for ex. if you get answer as "3" and you refresh, you so still get "3" but when I refresh it, currently. I get a different value due to the shuffling array.

here's the code I used to shuffle.

```
<?php

$answer = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");

shuffle($answer);

echo $answer;

?>
```

Comment: Check if the value being submitted (the users answer) is being sent, if not then shuffle as you current do, otherwise check the answer.

Comment: You would either need to pass the question array order in url parameters, set in session, set in a cookie, or set in HTML5 localStorage.  Have you made any efforts along these lines?

Comment: @MikeBrant no I haven't. I'm new at this but I will research what you referred. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeBrant is it possible with {if else, elseif} statements

Comment: Yeah, you can make conditions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will require a persistent number across a user's browsing session. Your best bet is to draw a random number and to set the number as cookie, or even to pass it along as a field parameter (which is not safe, but with proper sanitizing, the worst that can happen is that the order of the elements isn't persistent anymore.)

Replace 123 with a random, consistent number for each visitor to achieve the same order.

```
$answer = range(1, 6);

consistent_shuffle($answer, 123);
var_dump($answer);

function consistent_shuffle(&$input, $seed) {
    srand($seed);
    usort($input, function($a, $b) {
        return rand(-1, 1);
    });
    srand();
}
```

By passing the same number to [`srand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php) we will always get the same numbers when we call `rand()`. Note, however, that the order is not necessarily the same on two different machines – the only guarantee is that the order is the same on the same machine, which is what we need.

[`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is a function that sorts arrays with a user defined function. We supply one that draws randomly -1, 0 or 1.

Calling `srand()` at the end of the function guarantees that any calls to `rand()` after using `consistent_shuffle` won't always be the same. Omitting this might cause you a lot frustration trying to find the cause for a weird bug when you'll really want a random number for each reload.

This function works with any kind of keys and values but, akin to `shuffle()`, keys won't be kept after the array has been modified.